# How to accept facebook lead generation terms of service (TOS) through API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-ads

We want to run ads on behalf of our clients. Our process involves sending a page access request to our client. Once they accept, we can run ads for their Facebook page using a system user. However, when creating an Ad Set, we encounter the error 'you can't run lead ads until your Facebook page accepts Facebook's lead generation terms of service.' According to the documentation, we have to accept this for each page manually just and only through the UI, which is not scalable.
1- Is there a way to streamline this process and accept TOS with API?
2- Additionally, only users who have accepted these terms can create an Ad Set. Since I want to create Ad Sets with a system user, how can a system user accept these terms?

Thank in advance!